# Why is my discord bot code not running anything?

Tags: python, discord.py

Okay so I wanted to make a discord bot for my first python project. However, despite my seemingly correct code, the bot doesn't run:

[image: Dicord bot]

I used this basic code to simply get the bot online but nothing happens. I haven't seen anyone else have this problem either.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

    client.run("Token") # i removed the token for security
```

and this is the result of the program

[image: result]

Am I doing something wrong?

I am using this version of the discord botting API: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py

Comment: `client.run('<your-token>')`

Comment: `client.run("Token")` is incorrectly tabbed underneath the `on_ready` function. Remove the preceding whitespace and try running your bot again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jwjhdev said, `client.run` is not supposed to be tabbed under `on_ready`. If you delete the tab, then everything should work perfectly.